# How to avoid sorting pivot table by index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
t1=r.data[(r.data['test_num']==2) & (r.data['el_num'] < 4)]

     test_num  el_num  file_num     dose  is_anneal     value   fail
99          2       1         0    100.0      False -0.000056  False
100         2       1         1   5052.0      False -0.000056  False
101         2       1         2  10107.0      False -0.000056  False
102         2       1         3  16561.0      False -0.000056  False
103         2       1         4  22536.0      False -0.000056  False
104         2       1         5  25020.0      False -0.000056  False
105         2       1         6  35123.0      False -0.000056  False
106         2       1         7     24.0       True -0.000056  False
107         2       1         8    168.0       True -0.000055  False
108         2       2         0    100.0      False -0.000056  False
109         2       2         1   5052.0      False -0.000056  False
110         2       2         2  10107.0      False -0.000056  False
111         2       2         3  16561.0      False -0.000056  False
112         2       2         4  22536.0      False -0.000056  False
113         2       2         5  25020.0      False -0.000056  False
114         2       2         6  35123.0      False -0.000056  False
115         2       2         7     24.0       True -0.000056  False
116         2       2         8    168.0       True -0.000055  False
117         2       3         0    100.0      False -0.000060  False
118         2       3         1   5052.0      False -0.000061  False
119         2       3         2  10107.0      False -0.000061  False
120         2       3         3  16561.0      False -0.000061  False
121         2       3         4  22536.0      False -0.000061  False
122         2       3         5  25020.0      False -0.000061  False
123         2       3         6  35123.0      False -0.000061  False
124         2       3         7     24.0       True -0.000061  False
125         2       3         8    168.0       True -0.000061  False
```

When I want to create pivot table, I get this:

```
print(t1.pivot(index='dose',columns='el_num',values='value'))

el_num          1         2         3
dose                                 
24.0    -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
100.0   -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000060
168.0   -0.000055 -0.000055 -0.000061
5052.0  -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
10107.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
16561.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
22536.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
25020.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
35123.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
```

But I want the `dose` column to have an order like in the main table:

```
100.0
5052.0
10107.0
16561.0
22536.0
25020.0
35123.0
24.0
168.0
```

How to avoid sorting in pivot table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use solution what is similar `pivot_table`, but if duplicates it aggregate values:

```
df = t1.groupby(['dose','el_num'], sort=False)['value'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
el_num          1         2         3
dose                                 
100.0   -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000060
5052.0  -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
10107.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
16561.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
22536.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
25020.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
35123.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
24.0    -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
168.0   -0.000055 -0.000055 -0.000061
```

Another solution is use `pivot` and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by custom order:

```
a = t1.loc[t1['el_num'] == 1,'dose']

df = t1.pivot(index='dose',columns='el_num',values='value').reindex(a)
print (df)
el_num          1         2         3
dose                                 
100.0   -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000060
5052.0  -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
10107.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
16561.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
22536.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
25020.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
35123.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
24.0    -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
168.0   -0.000055 -0.000055 -0.000061
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `file_num`s are already sorted in the desired order, you could use

```
(t1.set_index(['file_num','dose','el_num']['value']
   .unstack('el_num').reset_index('file_num', drop=True))
```

which yields

```
el_num          1         2         3
dose                                 
100.0   -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000060
5052.0  -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
10107.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
16561.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
22536.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
25020.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
35123.0 -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
24.0    -0.000056 -0.000056 -0.000061
168.0   -0.000055 -0.000055 -0.000061
```

The `set_index/unstack` operation is similar to pivoting except that it allows more than one column to be used as the index. `file_num` is included to enforce the desired row order.